# Turn On Air Play on iPad Without Double Tapping Home Button

Tags: ipad, appletv, airplay

Is there a way to enable Air Play Mirroring on the iPad without (!) double tapping the  home button?

I'd like to physically lock away the home button to use the iPad on a booth but still be able to mirror the screen on an Apple TV. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have gestures enabled, you can swipe up using 4 fingers and then scroll to the left to access Air Play.

Not sure of any other ways.